# pandas.date_range -- freq="WOM-3FRI", how to understand that offset alias?

Tags: pandas

I've been trying to learn pandas in a lab class.  One part of our lab manual goes over generating time-based indices with the `date_range` function.  The class's lab manual says

> The `freq` parameter accepts a variety of string representations, referred to as *offset aliases*. See Table 1.3 for a sampling of some of the options. For a complete list of the options, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases.

I checked through the 'offset-alias' and 'anchored offsets' sections of the online documentation. Most of the entries in table 1.3 can be understood from those two sections.

However, the last entry of the table is `"WOM-3FRI"`  The table says this  corresponds to a frequency of every 3rd Friday of the month.  I have no idea how to deduce that from the online documentation.  It looks like `"WOM"` is being used as the alias and `"3FRI"` is being used as an anchor.  But, `"WOM"` is not listed as an alias in the online documentation.  So, I'm struggling to make sense of what's happening here.

One hypothesis I have is that this is some sort of operation.
The online documentation and my lab book have a couple examples where prepending a number in front of an alias increases the length of a the period by that number.  So, '2' operates in a way so that '2M' creates a frequency of every 2 months.  Similarly, '5' operates in a way so that '5Y' creates a frequency of every 5 years.  Does 'O' somehow operate in a way that the offset alias 'XOY' gives the xth sub-period of period Y?  For example, would "MOY-5" give the 5th month of the year?  Would "DOY-7FRI" give the 7th Friday of the year?

Another hypothesis I have is that `"MOA"` is a new-fangled alias, and `"3FRI"` is an anchor for it.  However, the documentation online does not list `"MOA"`. I checked, and it was pandas 0.23.4 documentation.  My lab machine is running version 0.23.4, and it can handle "WOM-3FRI" just fine.  Have they just not updated the documentation yet?

Would anyone could clear up the method/theory behind creating `"WOM-3FRI"`?

Lab manual with Table 1.3: http://www.acme.byu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Pandas4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more digging.  It looks like `"WOM"` is just an undocumented offset alias.  Source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2289#issuecomment-269616457

Answer (score 0):

read [pandas DateOffsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html):

WeekOfMonth - 'WOM' - the x-th day of the y-th week of each month

And see example here [exercise](https://github.com/ajcr/100-pandas-puzzles/blob/master/100-pandas-puzzles-with-solutions.ipynb)

37. Create a DateTimeIndex consisting of the third Thursday in each month for the years 2015 and 2016.

`pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2016-12-31', freq='WOM-3THU')`